# In ArcGIS, using 'Select by Location' and pushing selected features to a new table or feature?

Tags: arcgis-desktop

I have a layer with about 100 buildings and another layer that shows the extent of a flood. When I use the 'select by location,' it selects the ~50 buildings that would be underwater if a flood occurred. Is there a way to take those 50 selected polygons and push it to a new/separate layer or table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has a straightforward solution. The below steps are copied directly from the link provided below, and should be applicable to most (if not all) versions of ArcGIS:

1. In ArcMap, select features using any selection method.
2. Right-click the layer that contains the selected features, point to Data > 
   Export Data.
3. Click Export > Selected Features.
4. Make a selection for the coordinate system to use.
5. For the Output feature class text box, click the Browse button and navigate 
   to the existing geodatabase to which you will export.
6. Type the name for the new feature class you will create.
7. Click OK.

http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/manage-data/geodatabases/export-selected-features-with-the-export-data-command.htm

Answer (score 4):

Right-click on the layer in the Table of Contents -> Data -> Export Data... Make sure Selected features is selected in the Export box and then specify the path you want to save the new layer in.

[image]